# Why do we say that when a definite integral equals infinity it diverges?

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

When we are in the process of calculating an improper integral,specifically the type II ones,we say that if the limit does not exist then the integral diverges.

But isn't it rational to say that an infinite sum (the definite integral) is equal to infinity?Why can't we say that this sum=infinity?Is it because the idea of an infinite area is geometrically quite abstract?

Thank you!

Comment: They are not the same thing. For example, the improper integral of $x \mapsto x \sin x $ diverges but it has no limit.

Comment: Who are "we"${}$?

Comment: Infinity is not a number, so it is not rational to say that an infinite sum (or divergent integral) "equals" infinity.

Comment: Jeez folks, relax.

Comment: You can say that an infinite series or integral tends to $+∞$ or $-∞$, but saying that it diverges automatically implies that the limit is not finite. Clearly the infinite sum 1-1+1-1+1-1+.... diverges, but you can't say anything about whether it goes to plus or minus infinity or 0.

Comment: Saying that an infinite sum/integral is equal to infinity is more specific than saying that it diverges, it means that partial sums/integrals grow without a bound. They could stay bounded and oscillate instead, or even oscillate without a bound on absolute values.